# Downgrading a Windows administrator user

Tags: windows-10, administrator

In order to up the security on my device, I wanted to create a seperate administrator account on my windows 10 machine. Previously, my sole account on the machine was an administrator.

I created a new account as administrator and downgraded the existing one to a normal one. When entering via system settings -> users, it is shown correctly.

However, if I press Windows and right-click on the tiny user image on the left and select "change settings", the user is displayed as administrator. If I install software from that account, I don't have to enter any password, but I set the most restrictive setting in the UAC. Any adivce?

Comment: What software we're you installing? Some software does not require admin rights to install. Have you logged out and back on yet?

Comment: Are you trying to downgrade **an** administrator account, or **the** Administrator account? If it's **the** built-in Administrator account, the correct action is to **disable** that account.